# networkx issue with write_pajek

Tags: python, networkx

I am using python 2.7 and networkx 1.8 for some graph processing and I am trying to output my graph that contains node labels, to Pajek's `.net` format.

Networkx seems not to surround node labels with double quotes as required by the [format](https://gephi.org/users/supported-graph-formats/pajek-net-format/).

My code is pretty simple

```
    for link in links:
        graph.add_node(label)
        graph.add_edge(label, link)

    nx.write_pajek(graph, 'path_to_file.net', encoding = 'UTF-8')
```

Have you faced something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the quoted text is needed?

From the documentation of pajek [linked to by the networkx manual](http://vlado.fmf.uni-lj.si/pub/networks/pajek/doc/draweps.htm):

> label - if label starts with character A..Z or 0..9 first blank
>   determines end of the label (example: vertex1), labels consisting of
>   more words must be enclosed in pair of special characters (example:
>   "vertex 1")

And when trying an example graph with four nodes named {12, 13, single, 'multi part'},
I obtain the following output,

```
*network NetworkX
*vertices 4
1 "multi part" 0.0 0.0 ellipse
2 single 0.0 0.0 ellipse
3 12 0.0 0.0 ellipse 
4 13 0.0 0.0 ellipse
*arcs
1 3 1.0
2 3 1.0
```

which quotes the long text labels but not numeric or short labels -- i.e it matches the standard described above.

Comment: Thanks for the information. It turns out that this is not an issue with networkx but rather with Gephi that I used for reading the graph. In Pajek it works as intended but with Gephi the node labels are not shown